# How can I change the background color of only the first cell in listview in javafx?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

How can I change the background color of only the first cell in listview in JavaFX?I only want to change the background color of the first cell in the listview. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: What color would you want the first cell to be when it's selected?

Comment: Thank for your reply. No, I want to display the color in the cell without being selected. So, I mean whenever somebody sees my listview, they will find the first cell always colored Blue.

Comment: Right, what I mean is, what do you expect to happen when that cell is actually selected? Are you looking to prevent JavaFX from highlighting that cell and keep whatever color you set manually?

Comment: Seems to me that would not be an intuitive design as a user would expect some visual feedback if they click the first cell...

Comment: So, I have a text called posts in the first cell of the listview and in the following cells, I have all the posts. But as Post is the title of the listview, I want first cell to be colored so that it looks good.

Comment: The user will not click on it. It is just a title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to implement a custom `CellFactory` on the `ListView`. We can then determine if the cell belongs to the first item in the `List` you used to populate the `Listview`.  If so, apply a different style to just that cell.

*I am not aware if there is a way to determine the first **cell** of a `ListView`, but we can certainly capture the first item in a `List`.*

Consider the following application.  We have a `ListView` that just displays a list of strings.

We set a custom `CellFactory` on the `ListView` and set the cell style if the `item` is the first in the `List` populating the `ListView`.

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create the ListView
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().setAll("Title", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");

        // Set the CellFactory for the ListView
        listView.setCellFactory(list -> {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        // There is no item to display in this cell, so leave it empty
                        setGraphic(null);

                        // Clear the style from the cell
                        setStyle(null);
                    } else {
                        // If the item is equal to the first item in the list, set the style
                        if (item.equalsIgnoreCase(list.getItems().get(0))) {
                            // Set the background color to blue
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-text-fill: white");
                        }
                        // Finally, show the item text in the cell
                        setText(item);

                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        });

        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **The Result**

[image: screenshot]

---

Obviously, you'll need to make some adjustments to match your data model and just matching by a `String` would not be the best approach.

This does not prevent the user from selecting the first item and may not work as expected if the list is sorted after building the Scene.

While this may answer your direct question, there are other things to consider in order to ensure a good experience for the user.

Comment: correct - but you want to remove the style again when the cell is empty (or the item null, which is not necessarily the same). No way to grab the cell, actually, you must not even try because there's no control whatsoever when it's re-used or removed.